# Need Android app for my memoir book

Tags: software, tools, memoir

I've watched about 4 videos on YouTube about top apps to write books, but these videos don't explain anything about memoir-writing.  I would like an app that can sync to a cloud, preferably OneDrive, so it backs up my work.

I'm writing a memoir on my life and I've just noticed that I use my phone more than my laptop, so something that I could get access to on my laptop as well.  I'm using text to speech because I have really bad vision.  At the moment on using Google docs and Microsoft OneDrive but I'm not happy with either of these because I am splitting my text between these apps and as one can imagine it becomes messy.

TL;DR: I need an app that works on an Android, syncs to a cloud, and has professional tools.

Comment: In what ways do you think memoir writing would be different from any other writing with regards to the app you use? What's specific about memoirs?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  And consider a unique name for yourself.  I don't know about Android/Google/PCs but on my Mac a lot of my apps just sync between phone and computer without my having to do anything.  I use the Notes app all the time this way, for example.  But Google Docs might be better for Word and Word-style files and longer documents.

Comment: You have two questions here.  Both are legit, but they ought to be separated into different questions.  1) An app good for writing that syncs between your phone and computer and backs up.  2) Memoir writing (which is too broad as is but you could ask a bunch of different questions and might want to start with whatever is most pressing, if it hasn't been asked here before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend continuing to use Google Drive, and just moving all your work over from OneDrive to Google, which is pretty easy to do--just copy and paste the text or upload the file from your computer/phone.

Google Drive and Google Docs are both applications you can download on Android and are pretty user-friendly.  I use Google Drive for all my writing and school-related projects and find it very convenient because all I need is an Internet connection and my Google login.

Comment: I would like to add to that, that you do not need an internet connection as Android will make the Google Docs file availabile *offline*.